# getting the total of 3rd items on a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program that adds only the third item in a list with dictionaries. Please help me. Here is my code so far.

```
# SalesManager Code


# pseudo sales list


sales = {"Meat Loaf": [50, 69, 19],
         "Mineral Water": [5, 15, 10]
         }


for key, value in sales.items():
    total = total + value[2]
    print(total)
```

Comment: Post the desired output and what output you got with your current code?

Answer (score 1):

Define `total` outside the loop:

```
total = 0

for key, value in sales.items():
    total = total + value[2]
    print(total)

print(total) # 29
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below one liner code to achieve this:

```
print(sum(v[2] for v in sales.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to declare your variable `total`:

```
sales = {"Meat Loaf": [50, 69, 19],
         "Mineral Water": [5, 15, 10]
         }


total = 0
for key, value in sales.items():
    total = total + value[2]
    print(total)
```